# Some Windows clients do not appear in Samba's DNS after joining Samba domain

Tags: dns, samba4

I'm in the process of migrating my old PDC domain to Active Directory with Samba4 (4.5.2). What I did was quite straightforward - leave old domain, revert registry changes that allowed Windows 7/8 to use PDC domains, reboot, join new domain.

Now some of the clients do not appear in Samba's DNS, even though they have joined with the domain and work fine. I checked whether I forgot to revert the registry changes, but I haven't. And of those which updated DNS, some are ALLCAPS while some are not.

All Windows clients are pretty much out of the box, there are no HOST entries.
What might be the problem? Is it possible to trigger the clients to update Samba's DNS without rejoining them?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I didn't know how Windows handles DNS here. Once a computer joins, a DNS record will be created. If the computer shuts down properly, it will tell the AD and have it's record „tombstoned“, which means that it doesn't appear in the respective snap in and is not resolvable anymore.
Sometimes, however, clients seem to fail to notify AD - either when shutting down or booting up. When it fails to do so at startup, „ipconfig /registerdns“ can be used to re-trigger the process.